# How am I getting this Oracle Exception when Liquibase is creating it's Lock Table?

Tags: java, oracle, liquibase, dropwizard, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I've got a DropWizard service that I've setup so that any Liquibase migrations happen automatically at app startup.

When I first startup my Dropwizard service I run a `Liquibase::listLocks()` for informational purposes. This call will also create the `DATABASECHANGELOG` and `DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK` tables if they don't exist as a side effect.

*Once* on a new Oracle ATP DB, it threw the following error when creating the Lock table during that listLocks call:

```
ERROR 2021-07-08 17:59:22,546  [main] com.blah.utils.LiquibaseMigrator: Error listing locks!
liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ORA-12838: cannot read/modify an object after modifying it in parallel
 [Failed SQL: (12838) INSERT INTO DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK (ID, LOCKED) VALUES (1, 0)]
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:430)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:87)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:159)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:139)
    at liquibase.lockservice.StandardLockService.init(StandardLockService.java:128)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.checkLiquibaseTables(Liquibase.java:1176)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.listLocks(Liquibase.java:1193)
    at com.blah.utils.LiquibaseMigrator.dbLocksExist(LiquibaseMigrator.java:xxx)
    at com.blah.utils.LiquibaseMigratorExecutor.dbLocksExist(LiquibaseMigratorExecutor.java:xxx)
    at com.blah.MyApp.migrateDatabase(MyApp.java:xxx)
    at com.blah.MyApp.run(MyApp.java:xxx)
    at com.blah.MyApp.run(MyApp.java:xxx)
    at io.dropwizard.cli.EnvironmentCommand.run(EnvironmentCommand.java:59)
    at io.dropwizard.cli.ConfiguredCommand.run(ConfiguredCommand.java:98)
    at io.dropwizard.cli.Cli.run(Cli.java:78)
    at io.dropwizard.Application.run(Application.java:94)
    at com.blah.MyApp.main(MyApp.java:xxx)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-12838: cannot read/modify an object after modifying it in parallel
```

The service would throw that exception, then the pod would restart, and repeated. I manually added the row into the lock table that it was trying to insert there, and the next startup succeeded.

There was only 1 pod running at the time, so I don't think it's related to this [Race Condition on startup](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/issues/1584) bug I found, but I'm at a loss to why/how it could have gotten itself into this `cannot read/modify an object after modifying it in parallel` state.

Comment: it has nothing to do with race conditions. It is most likely that liquibase script is inserting data either with append hint, or parallel one, and then trying another insert without commit between.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you are connecting to a LOW service, which does not use parallel DML